# RedBeanPHP и PHP: поиск и вывод данных

Tags: php, html, redbeanphp

Подскажите, пожалуйста, на простом примере, как вывести список зарегистрированных пользователей из БД, используя поиск по двум критериям, по имени и городу?

```
require_once('db.php');
$user = R::load('users');
$name;
$city;
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stackoverflow! Предоставьте, пожалуйста, весь код и структуру БД.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш index.php файл будет выглядеть так:

```
<form action="/test.php" method="POST">
    <table width="100" height="50">
        <tr>
            <td>Поиск:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Искать здесь...">
                <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Город">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><button type="submit" name="do_search">Поиск</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Изменяйте его на ваше усмотрение, поле город добавил быстро, не проверяя, поэтому может съехать.

Файл test.php:

```
<?php

require_once('db.php');

if (!isset($_POST['do_search'])) {
    exit("Internal server error."); // Если не нажата кнопка поиска, то принудительно останавливаем выполнение скрипта
}

if(!$keywords = $_POST['search'] ?: null) {
    exit("Keyword is empty."); // Если поле пустое, то останавливаем скрипт
}

$sql = "name LIKE ?"; // Инициализируем sql запрос согласно правилам RedBean
$bind = [$keywords]; // Биндим параметр $keywords - поисковые слова

if($city = $_POST['city'] ?: null) {
    $sql .= " AND city = ?"; // Если есть поле город и оно не пустое, то добавляем к строке
    $bind[] = $city;    // Добавляем еще один бинд
}

$users = R::find('users', $sql, $bind); // Достаем всех юзеров по условию

var_dump($users);   // Здесь вывод юзеров, можете сделать на свое усмотрение, как хотите
```

Полезные ссылки:

- [R::find()](https://redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/finding)
- [Оператор ?:](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php)
- [exit()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)
- [Binding params](https://redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/querying)

Comment: а можно на примере использования поисковой формы и вывода в таблицу?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, указать в ответе сверстанную html-форму, структуру таблицы и скрипт сервера?

Comment: я добавил действующий код формы, таблицы и скрипта, помогите пожалуйста с поиском по бд

Comment: Постараюсь написать самую простую реализацию)

Comment: Какую версию php используете?

Comment: php 5.6, я все сделал на основе ваших рекомендаций, спасибо! но как бы еще сделать поиск из одной формы, но по разным значениям?

Comment: Под разным значениям? Объясните на примере.

Comment: например, в одно и то же поле <input type="search" name="search"> сначала ввожу имя, вывожу всех найденных в таблицу, затем возвращаюсь в эту же форму поиска и ввожу город, и также вывожу в таблицу

Comment: использовать одно поле для поиска по нескольким условиям - проблематично, но можете закостылить sql запрос и получится что-то такое: `SELECT * from users WHERE city = town OR name = town `